# How to save a response as example with Postman API

Tags: postman, newman, postman-mocks

I'm using postman MockServer feature.
I have 2 collections in Postman. One for my real server, and the other for the mock.
Postman MockServer need examples to mock a response when you make a request call.

[image]

I need to automate the creation of new examples. I think about Postman API or Newman to do so.

But I can't find anything in the documentation about saving new examples.

Any idea ?